# How to do integration over a unit sphere with 3 independent vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, spherical-coordinates

I got this equation I want to integrate over a sphere:

$min( max(-vSurfaceToCameraDir \cdot (vLight + vNormal * A), 0), 1 )^B$

A & B are constants and vSurfaceToCameraDir, vLight & vNormal are unit vectors that can point in any direction. If A=0 this could be expressed as $\int_{0}^{2π}{\int_{0}^{π/2} cosθ^Bsinθ \,dθ}\,dφ$ which would add up to π/(B + 1). However with vNormal there's a 3rd independent vector and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Is there some analytical way to compute this? If not I suppose I can do a numeric integration by making lots of random samples but I thought there might be some more elegant & faster way.

Comment: To integrate on the sphere, we need a point on the sphere. Which one is it in the formula?

Comment: The "point" is only implicitly defined. vSurfaceToCameraDir, vLight, vNormal all share a common point. This is the center of the unit sphere I want to integrate. Here's an article describing the domain of the problem I'm trying to solve, http://www.rorydriscoll.com/2009/01/25/energy-conservation-in-games/.

Comment: It could be an XY problem. You could perhaps explain exactly where the above formula comes from. In particular in the integral version that you give, there is no max and min, where have they gone?

Comment: The formula above is used to compute the translucency lighting for an object, it's not physically based but gives feasible approximation. I want to integrate this over a unit sphere so I can establish scaling factor for the translucency relative other parts of the lighting, i.e. the outgoing light energy should not exceed the incoming amount. So $min( max(-vSurfaceToCameraDir \cdot (vLight + vNormal * A), 0), 1 )^B$ is the outgoing light I want to integrate for all directions over the unit sphere.

Comment: At the center of the unit sphere is the point we compute the translucency lighting. vSurfaceToCameraDir is the unit vector from this location to eye/camera. vLight is the dir of incoming light and vNormal is the normal vector of the surface/geometry.

Comment: The case of $A = 0$ is computed by fixing vLight and then integrate vSurfaceToCameraDir over a unit sphere using spherical coordinates. However with $A \ne 0$ there are 2 independent vectors that can point in any direction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T \left(s\right) = \min  \left(1 , \max  \left(0 , s\right)\right)$ and $\overrightarrow{w} =-\left({\overrightarrow{v}}_{\text{light}}+A {\overrightarrow{v}}_{\text{normal}}\right)$. Assuming we want the integral

\begin{equation}
I = \int_{{S}^{2}}^{}T \left({\left(\overrightarrow{{\xi}} \cdot  \overrightarrow{w}\right)}^{B}\right) d \sigma(\overrightarrow{{\xi}}) = 2 {\pi} \int_{0}^{1}T \left({\left|w\right|}^{B} {s}^{B}\right) d s
\end{equation}

If $\left|w\right|  \leqslant  1$ we have

\begin{equation}
I = 2 {\pi} {\left|w\right|}^{B} \int_{0}^{1}{s}^{B} d s = \frac{2 {\pi} {\left|w\right|}^{B}}{B+1}
\end{equation}

If $\left|w\right|  \geqslant  1$ we have

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \begin{array}{rcl}I&=&\displaystyle  2 {\pi} {\left|w\right|}^{B} \int_{0}^{1/\left|w\right|}{s}^{B} d s+2 {\pi} \int_{1/\left|w\right|}^{1}d s\\
&=&\displaystyle  \frac{2 {\pi}}{\left(B+1\right) \left|w\right|}+2 {\pi} \left(1-\frac{1}{\left|w\right|}\right)
\end{array}
\end{equation}